# Cannot find network connection in KDE

Tags: 12.04, kde

I used network connection to connect to Internet (Dongle) which automatically detect my device in GNOME but when I Log off to KDE I cannot find networking connection and I cannot connect to Internet, I found only network tool which I can't figure it to connect.

Answer (score 0):

give a right click at your KDE panel at left option after time , it will gives you like this [image]

Among that select System tray settings and it will open a window like this [image] . In this window select Network management in Extra Items .Then you will have network applet at your panel .

By using that you can manage your network connections .

Comment: I cannot find Network Management or even Device Notifier in Extra Items.

Comment: how you have installed kde ?

Comment: I have just followed Saeed Zarinfam suggested link http://handytutorial.com/install-kde-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise/